# Convert AAX (Audible) audio file to MP3

Tags: audio, file-converter

I'd like to convert an AAX audio file (audio book downloaded from Audible) to MP3 so I can listen to it on an older portable device, which does not support this format, nor use of apps such as the Audible App. I found online converters limited to 200 MB (whereas my file is a bit larger than that), and offline (desktop-installable) ones that I'd rather not install or that are not free.

Two such installable converters are:

- https://github.com/audiamus/AaxAudioConverter : detected as malware by VirusTotal
- https://sourceforge.net/projects/aaxtomp3/ : only converts to a 0KB MP3 file

Any recommendations how I get this done on Windows, using free software (with or without a GUI) or free online services?

Comment: Well, we do not support [howtos](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/185) here – but as it looks like you'd also be satisfied with a recommendation for good software: could you please specify what OS must be supported, and what your price limit would be if it comes to paid solutions? Also, must it offer a GUI, or would command-line solutions be acceptable as well?

Comment: Thanks! I actually thought this site is more suitable than SuperUser since no software is known/proposed for this problem (from the linked meta: "A question asking how to accomplish a task with some specific software, as opposed to looking for some software to accomplish that task, would be off-topic. Such questions would typically be on-topic for Super User for end-user software"). In any even, I've edited the question to reflect the missing info. Thanks again!

Comment: Well… With the question rather asking for "how I get this done on Windows", it might indeed fit better on SuperUser. Here the focus is rather "what software meets the requirements". That apart, first piece coming to mind is [FFmpeg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFmpeg), which handles quite a lot of formats (and runs on many platforms).